# cocos2d flicker

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a pool of CCSprites numbering 1200 in each of two arrays, displayGrid1 and displayGrid2.  I turn them visible or invisible when showing walls or floors.  Floors have a number of different textures and are not z-order dependent.  Walls also have several textures and are z-order dependent.

I am getting about 6-7 frames when moving which is okay because its a turn based isometric rogue-like.  However, I am also getting a small amount of flicker, which I think is performance related, because there is no flicker on the simulator.

I would like to improve performance.  I am considering using an array CCSpriteBatchNodes for the floor which is not z-order dependent but am concerned with the cost of adding and removing sprites frequently between the elements of this array, which would be necessary I think.

Can anyone please advise as to how I can improve performance?

Comment: How are you loading your sprites? Are you loading them using a sprite sheet or are you loading them as individual sprite files?

Comment: You might consider getting an App to compose your sprites into sprite sheets (aka Texture Atlas) which should be much more performant. By using a texture atlas instead, your App will utilize one larger texture to store a group of sprites instead of wasting memory storing excess pixel data for each individual sprite. Cocos2D has pretty good support for these and, from what I can tell, it is _much_ more performant this way. Creating individual sprites from a texture atlas is easy, you just call the sprite by name instead of from the file.

Comment: I'll try it.  Thanks.  Can I use different sprites from that texture atlas with the same CCSpriteBatchNode?  This would also improve performance I imagine.

Comment: Yes as long as the sprites reside within the same texture. So if wall and floor sprites are in the same texture atlas, then they should be able to be loaded using the same CCSpriteBatchNode.

Comment: Maybe you could put your comments in an answer form so I can "accept" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're using multiple small sprite files loaded individually which can cause performance issues as there is wasted memory being used to store excess pixel data around each of the individual sprites. Each row of pixel data in an OpenGL texture must have a number of bytes totaling a power of 2 for performance reasons. Although I believe OpenGL ES under iOS does this automatically, it can come with a big performance hit. Grouping sprites together into a single texture that is correctly sized can be a tremendous boon to rendering performance.

You can use an App like Zwoptex to group all these smaller sprite files into a larger, more manageable sprite sheets/texture atlas and utilize one CCSpriteBatchNode for each sprite sheet/texture atlas.

Cocos2D has pretty good support for utilizing sprite sheets with texture atlases and converting your code to using these instead of individual files can be done with little effort. Creating individual sprites from a texture atlas is easy, you just call the sprite by name instead of from the file.

CCSpriteBatchNodes group OpenGL calls for their sprites together, a process known as batching, which causes the operating system and OpenGL to have to make less round trips to the GPU which *greatly* improves performance. Unfortunately, CCSpriteBatchNodes are limited to only being able to draw sprites for the texture that backs them (enter sprite sheets/texture atlases).

Comment: Thanks.  I will at least be able to use this for my floor tiles.  My walls and other elements are unfortunately highly z-order dependent so I won't be able to use this technique for them.  I'm hopeful this will be enough of a performance boost, though.

Comment: The nice thing about Cocos2D is that the z-order of the sprite doesn't matter when it comes to how they're stored behind the scenes, so you should be able to pack your floor and wall sprites in the same texture and display them at different z-orders.